# How bucket number gets decide in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

When we store key-value pair in a hashmap, HaspMap looks for a hashcode of a key and store the pair in the bucket of which the identifier is the hash code of the key.

A bucket can have multiple pairs of key-value. If a bucket can keep multiple pairs of key-value then what about the keys which are not similar to each other but still shares the same hashcode.

How different keys of a same bucket can have a same hashcode...? May I know how it's working?

Comment: Because that's what a hash code is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How different keys of a same bucket can have a same hashcode...?

The `hashCode()` contract doesn't say that two objects that are not equals between them may not have the same hashcode.

If two objects have the same hashcode, these are in the same bucket but the `HashMap` doesn't rely only on `hashCode()`, it relies also on the `equals()` method to evaluate if two keys are equals.
Which means that the map looks for in each element of the bucket to see if the element is equals in terms of `equals()` with the input key.
If the input key is `equals()` with the element, these are equals.
That's why it is advised to reduce hashcode collision since it favors iteration lookup over hash lookup.

Here is the private `getNode()` method defined in `HashMap` (Java 8) that retrieves a key from the map :

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can see that a key of the map matches with an input key only if their `hashcode()` values are the same and that these are "`equals()`".

Comment: Make sense..!! Could you please explain your statement "it favors iteration lookup over hash " ? I didnt get it. Secondly, what makes different keys to produce same hashcode..? Third, How can we get existing list of hashcodes in HashMap not the keys..? Thanks :)

Comment: "what makes different keys to produce same hashcode" this is a simple matter of counting. There are only 2^32 different hashcodes but many more different objects you can hash. So clearly some collisions must occur.

Comment: 1.If you have a lot of elements in the same bucket, the map has to iterate on potentially all elements to determinate if the input key is equals with one of the elements of the bucket(I added code to illusrate). 2.The way of implementing the `hashCode()` and `int` range. Even if it is well designed to provide a good distribution between objects, it may not be perfect. It if often a trade-off between speed and distribution. Having a few collisions is generally not a problem. Having frequent enough collision is. 3. Of course. Retrieve keys (`keySet()`)and invoke `hashCode()` on each one of them.