# Bucket definition in HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I'm trying to understand how a bucket(index) is determined in a hashmap by the key and I've read 3 ways to determine it, but there can't be 3.

```
1) index = hashCode(key) & (n-1)
2) index = hashcode % number of cells in the map
3) static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
   return h & (length-1);
}
```

I'm just starting to learn Java and I can't understand the 2500-line hashmap code. Please tell me how the index (bucket) is determined, what is the name of the method that does this and what line is it on? What is needed is not speculation, but links to documentation.

Comment: If you look at [`getNode`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ac2dfe45d1b7fb9b99b0ba1402189de1791319b8/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L573), you'll see the index is computed by `(n - 1) & hash(key)` (see line 576), where `hash` is [a method that computes the key's hash](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ac2dfe45d1b7fb9b99b0ba1402189de1791319b8/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L336).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How bucket number gets decide in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387087/how-bucket-number-gets-decide-in-hashmap)

Comment: (1) and (3) are the same by inspection, and (1) and (2) are the same because `h & (n-1)` and `h % n` are equal provided `n` is a power of two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 3 are the same.
1 and 3 are the same: `h` is just `hashCode(key)`, and `n` and `length` are the same too, which means they are the same.

The second one is also the same: `n` is always a power of two, which in bit terms means it's 00100000000 (exactly a single one-bit, all others are a zero), which means `n-1` is, in bits, always something like 00011111111 - all zeroes, then all ones.

`& x` where x is such a number simply means: where our `n` has 1-bits, don't do anything. Where there are 0-bits, the end result should also have 0 bits. Under all these rather specific conditions, `%n` and `& (n-1)` is actually the same mathematical operation.

For example, let's `n = 8`.

Then `& (n-1)` is the same as 'zero out all bits except the bottom 3.

Which is identical to `%8`. For example, `10 % 8` is 2, obviously. `10 & 7` is.. also 2.

> I'm just starting to learn Java and I can't understand the 2500-line hashmap code.

HashMap is one of the most complicated classes in there. Tell me, what do you think of this situation:

Jane: Hey, Jack, turned 16 I see? Starting driving lessons yet?

Jack: Yes. It's going allright.. I haven't gotten behind the wheel quite yet, first I decided to take apart the entire engine. I think I worked it out but see this screw on the side of this spark plug? It's aluminimum instead of steel. I'm looking for a book about material science because I really need to figure out this aluminium vs steel thing or I'll never be a good driver!

Jane: ....

Because.. you're Jack. Don't be like Jack.

Comment: Really
1) hashCode(key) & (n-1)
2) hashcode % number of cells in the map
if we take the starting hashmap array as 16 and imagine that our object returns a hashcode of 100, then we have the following:
1) 100 & (16-1) = 1100100(100) & 0001111 (15). Result 0000100  = 4 in decimal (this will go into bucket 4)
2) 100 % 16 = 4
thanks for the addition!

Comment: @MrSmith42 yes, I do. I shall edit the answer.